# unable to read or write in android datastore

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-datastore

I have a problem with android `datastore`.
I dont know that I can't write or I can't read but it doesn't work any way
here is my code:

```
class DataStoreProvider(private val context: Context) {
    private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by 
      preferencesDataStore("settings")
    private val phoneNumberKey = stringPreferencesKey("phoneNumberPreferencesKey")
    private val passwordKey = stringPreferencesKey("passwordPreferencesKey")

    fun readPhoneNumber(): String? {
        var phoneNumber: String? = null
        context.dataStore.data
            .map { preferences ->
                phoneNumber = preferences[phoneNumberKey]
            }
        return phoneNumber
    }

    suspend fun savePhoneNumber(phoneNumber: String) {
        context.dataStore.edit { setting ->
            setting[phoneNumberKey] = phoneNumber
        }
    }
}
```

I call these functions from `viewModelScope.launch` function on `Dispatchers.IO`.

and I use `1.0.0` version of data store
any idea what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactor your `readPhoneNumber` like this:

```
suspend fun readPhoneNumber(): String? {
    return context.dataStore.data
      .map { preferences -> preferences[phoneNumberKey] ?: null }
      .first()
}
```